# FlexSlider does not work - "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" (Typo3)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, typo3, flexslider

I'm trying to use the FlexSlider extension (1.50) on my Typo3 script. FlexSlider needs jQuery, so I added it by the extension T3 jQuery. Unfortunately the FlexSlider does not work. I get the following error:

"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function".

It refers to the second line of this code block:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(window).load(function() { 
    $('#fs-182.flexslider').flexslider(
    {
        animation: "fade",
        slideDirection: "horizontal",
        slideshow: false,
        slideshowSpeed: 7000,
        animationDuration: 600,
        controlNav: true,
        directionNav: false,
        keyboardNav: false,
        mousewheel: false,
        prevText: "Previous",
        nextText: "Next",
        pausePlay: false,
        pauseText: "Pause",
        playText: "Play",
        randomize: false,
        animationLoop: true,
        pauseOnHover: false

    });
});

</script>
```

Does anyone has an idea how to solve this problem?

Edit: jQuery is added two times to the file. In the header and in the body. I think the one in the header is added by T3 jQuery - it's the same version I choosed in the properties of T3 jQuery (2.1.0). The one in the body is an older version (1.10.2).

Comment: Are you sure jQuery is loaded before this code? Do you have a live exemple?

Comment: Do you add FlexSlider after jQuery?

Comment: I don't know why, but jQuery is added after FlexSlider. Do I have to add it before? If so, how can I achieve it with Typo3?

And I'm sorry, I can't show a live example.

Comment: Try solutions from this [discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551767/typo3-get-a-javascript-included-by-headerdata-to-load-before-one-included-by)

Comment: Try with a double quotes and see $("#fs-182.flexslider") ..

Comment: jQuery is added two times, see edit. I thought T3 jQuery would prevent it...

Answer (score 2):

This means that jQuery is not defined so you just need to figure out why it's not defined.  Loading it twice is not a good thing.

You should only need to load jQuery once, and make sure it's loaded before this script is.

Other than that you could try replacing $ with the actual text jQuery.

```
jQuery(window).load(function($) {
```

Or you could try wrapping it in an anonymous function

```
(function() {

})();
```

Comment: I think jQuery is added by the typo3 admin panel but I don't know how to prevent it.